# Avoiding predefined numeric constants conflicting with enumerations in C++

Tags: c++, enums, g++, naming-conventions

This question is related to [GCC says "syntax error before numeric constant" in generated header file from bison](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3473406/229311) and [I'm getting an error concerning enum (I think)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6289376/229311), but the answers there only gave the reason for why one might see the error, "error: syntax error before numeric constant." Unless I glossed over it, I didn't see any good solutions to avoid this problem (except of course to simply rename our enumeration constants). Thus, my question is: besides simply renaming enum constants to avoid this naming conflict, are there other (preferable) ways to get around this problem? Using namespaces does not seem to work.

UPDATE (for namespaces):
I get this error:

```
enum.cpp:5:5: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
enum.cpp:5:5: error: expected ‘}’ before numeric constant
enum.cpp:5:5: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
enum.cpp:7:1: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
```

from this program:

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

namespace mine {
  enum test {
    NCC
  };
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{ 
  return 0;
}
```

Note, I get the same error when compiling this program:

```
#define NCC 5

namespace mine {
  enum test {
    NCC
  };
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{ 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show how namespaces were applied so we can diagnose it.

Comment: If it's preprocessor symbols you're colliding with, namespaces won't help.

Comment: updated now with how namespaces doesn't seem to work.

Comment: This is why the preprocessor is regarded as poisonous in some circles.  Avoid names that are reserved by the headers that you use.

Comment: This gets annoying when developing a large application that works with certain enums for a while and then suddenly you include another header (e.g. sys/ioctl.h) that breaks everything! It's easy to avoid the reserved names when starting out... but including headers several months later that break things is what causes trouble.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know of to do this is to undefine the contants/symbols you're about to redefine in your enumeration:

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#undef NCC

namespace {
    enum {
        NCC
    }
}
```

This compiles.

Keep in mind that I'm assuming you really want to redefine that symbol.  If so, that's how you do it.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, you can use a namespace to keep them unconfused.